# wp enqueue js scripts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue a script in my WordPress `function.php`
I cant seem to get it to pick up the script.

**works in this format if include in header**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**however when i include in functions.php it dose not work**

```
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.6', true);
```

can anyone see why it will not work when I enqueue it ?

**FULL CODE**

```
function theme_js()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '3.1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.6', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('html5shiv-js', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.7.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('respond-js', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), null, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading it in the footer, which may not be what you mean to do. You have the final flag set to true.

*For reference*:

wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )

Try (now includes the de-register for the jQuery you are queuing):

**FULL CODE**

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
 function my_jquery_enqueue() {
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function theme_js(){
    // wp_enqueue_script('jquery-js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('html5shiv-js', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.7.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('respond-js', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

Additionally check: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3 at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.6:6 at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.6:6 ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this dose not work still, thanks anyways

Comment: Can you post the entire section of code from your functions file please

Comment: I trust its actually wrapped in an initialised function?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes it is and add_action

Comment: I would add "jquery-js" to the dependency array as good practise so: 
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery-js'), '3.3.6', true); In fact I see you have (incorrectly as I understand it) used "jquery" in a couple of the others.

Comment: Also to load jquery in this way you have to DE-register it first with something like:

if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

Comment: I added this to the code above. So it now de-registers the jquery, then enqueue it

Comment: Hmm still not working, ill keep on trying to get this to work then update your answer and accept

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it. I cannot imagine why it is not working now. Anything in console?

Comment: LOl, why did i not  check ha ha yes there is   `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
    at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.6:6
    at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.6:6 `

Comment: Me too, and if you accept my (edited) answer I finally wont have to see ads any more on here! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137079/discussion-between-mayersdesign-and-benjamin-oats).